# Blog Platforms which support SystemVerilog Syntax Highlighting

Tags: syntax, syntax-highlighting, blogs, syntaxhighlighter

I'm looking for a blog platform which supports SystemVerilog syntax highlighting.
It would be best if the feature is embedded in the platform, but I don't mind if it's supported as a third-party plugin. It's actually difficult to find the syntax highlighter that supports HDL, especially SystemVerilog.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, I'm using Javascript syntax highlighter [**highlight.js**](https://highlightjs.org/) at [**Blogger**](http://blogger.com).